# Combining Z-scores using Stouffer's approach

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, z-score

*Quick background:* I require to obtain a single 'score' for comparison between experimental and simulated data. The parameter being tested is the height of various parts (num = 5) of the model. For the experimental data, I will have the mean and standard deviations for each of the parts, whereas for the simulated data it will just be one value for each part.

My current approach was to evaluate the Z-scores for each part, and then combine them using Stouffer's method. I have three questions here:

1) Is my current approach appropriate, or are there better alternatives? (Do note that the data that I have is limited to the above)

2) When combining Z-scores using Stouffer's method, should we take sum of the absolute values of the Z-scores, or of their true values (with sign)? From what I have read on the Internet, it seems to be the latter. My concern in that case is that positive and negative Z-scores might cancel each other other and give me a score of 0... which wouldn't provide a correct interpretation of the accuracy of the model. Owing to this, I was tempted to use the absolute values.

3) Is it advisable to use weights here? If so, what can I use as as weights?